# How to change colour for barplot in ggplot2 using viridis package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]I am trying to make a ggplot with the viridis package (magma option) for colouring the bars. I keep going to the default colour option.

here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
barplotforraredisease <- data. frame(family = c(" Singleton", "Family of 2", "Family of 3", "Family of 4", "Family of 5"), total members=c(108,52,121,9,2))

p <- ggplot (data=barplotforraredisease, aes (x=family, y=total members))+geom bar(stat = "identity") +geomtext(aes (label=total members), vjust= -0.3, size = 3.5) +theme_minimal() +ggtitle( "Number of families tested")+scale color viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "viridis")
```

I've attached a screenshot of what my plot looks like, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted has some underscores replaced with spaces.

Once that is fixed, this should work. Note that you need to set the `fill` value to the column that you want, change `scale_color_viridis()` to `scale_fill_viridis()` and set `option = "magma"`.

```r
ggplot(
    data=barplotforraredisease, aes(
        x=family, y=total_members, fill=family)
    ) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=total_members), vjust= -0.3, size = 3.5) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    ggtitle( "Number of families tested") + 
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "magma")
```

[image]

### Data:

```r
barplotforraredisease  <- structure(list(family = c(" Singleton", "Family of 2", "Family of 3",
"Family of 4", "Family of 5"), total_members = c(108, 52, 121,
9, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```